# using a preposition after a noun

Tags: prepositions

What is the correct preposition for the noun 'blasphemer'? Is this 'of' or 'against'? I've seen online dictionaries but i found the answer nowhere.

Like, he is a blasphemer of the court.

or, he is a blasphemer against the court.

or, he is blasphemous to/ towards the court.

or, he is a blaspheming speaker against the court.

I'm confused.

Comment: Do you mean that he spoke irreverently about the court itself, or that he used bad language in court?

Comment: I have encountered a number of judges who seemed convinced that they were God, but any dictionary will tell you that blasphemy is speech showing disrespect for a deity (or religion).

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - Yes, I'm aware of that. That's why I asked what meaning the OP was actually trying to convey.

Comment: @KateBunting I meant 'you' the OP.

Comment: I didn't use the word 'God' on purpose because of some reason;  I just wanted to avoid a debate. Yes, I mean if he used bad language.  So, which is the best choice?

Comment: I think Anglophones in general [aren't big on "blasphemy" these days.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=blasphemy&year_start=1820&year_end=2000&corpus=26&smoothing=3) The chart in that link shows just how far the word itself has fallen out of favour over the past couple of centuries. Maybe it's because I was brought up in the Judeo-Christian tradition, but even though the usage is relatively uncommon today, I still associate it with being disrespectful to the Christian god (but it's invariably profane disrespect towards the *Islamic* God that makes the news today).

Comment: Then he blasphemed/used blasphemous language **in** court.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - there was a story about John Wesley out riding his horse, when he met a man looking utterly dejected. When asked why, he said that he had committed [the sin against the Holy Ghost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_sin) aged 7 and was uniquely bound for Hell. Wesley said 'I have met plenty of men like you', and, instantly, the man was cured of his melancholy.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: I find it hard to believe that sensible people ever believed such tosh! Apparently, for a mere 6 (old) pence 150 years ago I could have bought [this tract](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/The_Unpardonable_Sin_Or_Sin_Against_the/VQOaj6c72jAC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22sin+against+the+Holy+Ghost%22&printsec=frontcover) which would have enabled me to reliably distinguish between a "mere backslider" (who perhaps didn't go to church every week) and the truly "unpardonable sinner" (who specifically blasphemed again *The Holy Ghost*). I never knew that was "its own special sin".

Comment: @FumbleFingers - some Christian sects perform complicated mental contortions to reconcile the 'sin against the Holy Ghost', which cannot be forgiven, and the concept of a merciful and loving God. [Some](https://www.bibleinfo.com/en/questions/why-blasphemy-against-holy-spirit-unpardonable-sin) say that the sin consists of wilfully not letting the Holy Ghost into your soul, and thus disqualifying yourself from forgiveness.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: I was a choirboy for years until my voice broke, and it seems to me that our vicar's every other sermon was something to do with the difference between God the Father, God the Son, and The Holy Ghost (the church itself was actually called "The Holy Trinity" church). But I never understood it back then, and today I think it's just meaningless manipulation of symbols that don't actually have real-world referents anyway, so just because you can string words together using syntax/grammar doesn't imply they actually make sense.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Irreverent French people sometimes call the Holy Ghost _le pigeon_ because he is often depicted as a dove in religious art. The only Limerick I know in French is this one about the young atheist: Il y avait un jeune homme de Dijon/Qui n’aimait du tout la religon/Il dit: “Eh ma foi/Je deteste tous les trois/Le Pere, et le Fils, et le Pigeon”.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: I like it! I'm not exactly fluent in French, and I'd have missed the significance of the last word if you hadn't told me first, but I did find it easy to "recite" it in my head as I read the words. In the stereotypically *English* metre of iambic pentameter or similar, I believe. It got me thinking though, 'cos I stumbled over the scansion a bit at the end of the second line. And now I can't make up my mind whether it's at least "acceptable" in (modern, or "archaic") French to have ***religon*** as a 3-syllable term (rather than 4-syllable ***religion***). What say you?

Comment: @FumbleFingers it's a typo by me (sorry!) and I omitted the accents - Il y avait un jeune homme de Dijon - Qui n’aimait du tout la religion - Il dit "Eh ma foi! Je déteste tous les trois - Le Père, le Fils, et le Pigeon !

Answer (score 1):

In most countries in which English is the (or an) official language, the law has a term 'contempt of court' which is the offence ('offense' in US English) of being disobedient to or disrespectful toward a court of law and its officers in the form of behaviour/behavior that opposes or defies the authority, justice, and dignity of the court. A person committing such an offence would be 'a person guilty of contempt of court' or technically a 'contemnor' although use of this word is very rare outside legal documents.

A blasphemer is a person who, verbally or in writing, shows extreme disrespect to a deity or religion. Such a person would usually be said to blaspheme (or be a blasphemer) **against** or **towards** God, the Church, etc.

> Censorship was limited only to expression that (a) blasphemed against
> the church, (b) subverted the government, or (c) promoted immorality.

[Blasphemed (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/blasphemed)